# Changing the language of debugger message

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I am having a problem with my code. And before I can even get into what that problem might be I need to get the debugger to display its messages in english.

I am using VS Code on Windows 10 with its languages set to german and the debugger displays its messages in german which makes it really hard to google them.

How do I change the language setting?

Here is what I am getting now:

```
Einzelschritt: Nichtbenutzercode "..." wird übersprungen.
```